# sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer: fit_transform() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am working on an example of using `ColumnTransformer` and `LabelEncoder` for pre-processing the well-known Titanic data set `X`:

```
    Age Embarked    Fare    Sex
0   22.0    S      7.2500   male
1   38.0    C      71.2833  female
2   26.0    S      7.9250   female
3   35.0    S      53.1000  female
4   35.0    S      8.0500   male
```

Calling the transformer like this:

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ("label-encode categorical", LabelEncoder(), ["Sex", "Embarked"])
    ]
).fit(X).transform(X)
```

results in:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-fd5a05b7e47e> in <module>
      4         ("label-encode categorical", LabelEncoder(), ["Sex", "Embarked"])
      5     ]
----> 6 ).fit(X).transform(X)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in fit(self, X, y)
    418         # we use fit_transform to make sure to set sparse_output_ (for which we
    419         # need the transformed data) to have consistent output type in predict
--> 420         self.fit_transform(X, y=y)
    421         return self
    422 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in fit_transform(self, X, y)
    447         self._validate_remainder(X)
    448 
--> 449         result = self._fit_transform(X, y, _fit_transform_one)
    450 
    451         if not result:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in _fit_transform(self, X, y, func, fitted)
    391                               _get_column(X, column), y, weight)
    392                 for _, trans, column, weight in self._iter(
--> 393                     fitted=fitted, replace_strings=True))
    394         except ValueError as e:
    395             if "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead" in str(e):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    915             # remaining jobs.
    916             self._iterating = False
--> 917             if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
    918                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
    919 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    757                 return False
    758             else:
--> 759                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    760                 return True
    761 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    714         with self._lock:
    715             job_idx = len(self._jobs)
--> 716             job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    717             # A job can complete so quickly than its callback is
    718             # called before we get here, causing self._jobs to

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    180     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    181         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 182         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    183         if callback:
    184             callback(result)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    547         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    548         # arguments in memory
--> 549         self.results = batch()
    550 
    551     def get(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self)
    223         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    224             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 225                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    226 
    227     def __len__(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    223         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    224             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 225                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    226 
    227     def __len__(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _fit_transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, **fit_params)
    612 def _fit_transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, **fit_params):
    613     if hasattr(transformer, 'fit_transform'):
--> 614         res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    615     else:
    616         res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

TypeError: fit_transform() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

What is the problem with `**fit_params` here? To me this looks like a bug in `sklearn` or at least an incompatibility.

Comment: I am aware that there are tons of workarounds, but I am specifically looking for a solution that uses a single pipeline object for the entire preprocessing and applies label encoding

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are two major reasons why this will not work for your purpose.

1. `LabelEncoder()` is desinged to be used for the target variable (y). That is the reason for getting the positional argument error, when `columnTransformer()` tries to feed `X, y=None, fit_params={}`.

From [Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html):

> Encode labels with value between 0 and n_classes-1.
>
> **fit(y)**
> Fit label encoder
>
> **Parameters:**
> **y :** array-like of shape (n_samples,)
> Target values.

2. Even if you do a workaround to remove the empty dictionary, then also `LabelEncoder()` cannot take 2D array (basically multiple features at a time) because it takes only 1D `y` values.

Short answer - we should not be using `LabelEncoder()` for input features.

Now, what is the solution to encode the input features?

Use [`OrdinalEncoder()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html) if your features are ordinal features or [`OneHotEncoder()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder) in case of nominal features.

Example:

```py
>>> from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder, OneHotEncoder
>>> X = np.array([[1000., 100., 'apple', 'green'],
...               [1100., 100., 'orange', 'blue']])
>>> ct = ColumnTransformer(
...     [("ordinal", OrdinalEncoder(), [0, 1]),
         ("nominal", OneHotEncoder(), [2, 3])])
>>> ct.fit_transform(X)   
array([[0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0.]])
```

Comment: That explains it. I have seen LabelEncoder "misused" for feature encoding so often that I thought it is designed for this.

Comment: Just to be clear the empty dictionary is in fact the `fit_params`. If you walk through the code, you will see[`sklearn.pipeline._fit_transform_one`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.20.X/sklearn/pipeline.py#L612-L620) gets called with the `LabelEncoder` instance, the dataframe (`X`), `None` (`y`), and `{}` (the `fit_params`).

Answer (score 8):

I believe this is actually an issue with `LabelEncoder`. The `LabelEncoder.fit` method only accepts `self`, and `y` as arguments (which is odd as most transformer objects have the paradigm of `fit(X, y=None, **fit_params)`). Anyway, in pipeline the transformer gets called with `fit_params` regardless of what you have passed. In this particular situation the exact arguments passed to `LabelEncoder.fit` are `X` and an empty dictionary `{}`. Thus raising the error.

From my point of view this is a bug in `LabelEncoder`, but you should take that up with the sklearn folks as they may have some reason for implementing the `fit` method differently.

Comment: This is the correct answer. There's no reason a LabelEncoder can't/shouldn't be used for a feature. OneHotEncoding is NOT the same thing as label encoding. There could be instances where it doesn't make sense to use a large sparse structure or an ordinal encoding.

Comment: But what is your solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is called ***label*** encoder because it is meant to be used with the ***labels*** of your dataset i.e. the y values. This class confused me so much until I realized that.

It is confusing though because, in the literature, we either One-Hot Encode our features or Label Encode them. Sklearn isn't super friendly to newbies in that sense.

Use `OrdinalEncoder` instead, it is designed to work with features.